# Как реализовать ожидание пользовательского ввода в цикле, WinForms?

Tags: c#, сортировка, циклы, события, ввод

Есть некоторое приложение на C#, демонстрирующее пользователю в левой и правой части окна две фотографии. Суть приложения - отбор лучших по мнению пользователя фотографий, к примеру, из 1000 фотографий необходимо выбрать 100 лучших.

На мой взгляд тут хорошо подходит пирамидальная сортировка, в данном случае для выбора M лучших из N фотографий не влечет необходимости полной сортировки массива.

Но. Проблема в следующем. Разбить пирамидальную сортировку на части, которые бы хорошо вписывались как элементы обработки событий ввода я не вижу возможным.

Вопрос в следующем - как реализовать приложение, которое в некотором главном цикле ожидало бы внутри цикла сортировки клика пользователя по одной из двух фотографий. Диалоговые окна не приветствуются.

Если есть вопросы или альтернативные предложения решения задачи, с радостью отвечу.

Answer (score 1):

Раньше надо было бы, конечно, сохранять состояние сортировки вручную. Но сейчас-то всё совсем просто: объявите вашу процедуру как `async`, и в том месте, где нужно сравнить два объекта, вызовите `await PresentComparePhotos(photo1, photo2)`. Вам даже код не нужно будет менять.

(Процедура `PresentComparePhotos` должна, понятно, показывать пользователю фотографии, и дожидаться выбора.)

---

Для того, чтобы дождаться клика по фотографии, можно применить следующий код:

```
async Task<UIElement> ClickOnControl(UIElement el, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<UIElement>();
    MouseButtonEventHandler handler = (sender, args) => tcs.TrySetResult(el);
    el.MouseDown += handler;
    try
    {
        using (ct.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled()))
            return await tcs.Task;
    }
    finally
    {
        el.MouseDown -= handler;
    }
}
```

Чтобы дождаться клика на нескольких контролах, можно сделать как-то так:

```
async Task<UIElement> ClickOnAny(IEnumerable<UIElement> elements, CancellationToken ct)
{
    using (var innerCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct))
    {
        var tasks = elements.Select(el => ClickOnControl(el, innerCts)).ToList();
        var winningTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        var clickedControl = await winningTask;
        innerCts.Cancel();
        return clickedControl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Немного не понял, как совместить в одном "дожидаться выбора" в процедуре и обработчики OnClick фотографий.

Comment: @АлексейЕфремов: А причём тут `OnClick`? Не думайте в синхронных терминах. Ваш код должен (1) показать две нужные фотографии, (2) дождаться через `await` клика на любой из них, (3) проверить, на какой произошёл клик и вернуть это из `Task`'а. Если вы приведёте мне код, который делает (1) и подписывается на клик, я превращу вам его в нужный async-метод.

Comment: вот пункт 2 как раз и не понятен.

Comment: @АлексейЕфремов: Добавил в ответ